# Rounding time to whole seconds in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, rounding

I have a time column as

```
Time
07:34:23.554
08:44:42.778
08:11:38.332
```

I want to round off the seconds field so that if value after decimal is less than 0.5 it gets rounded down and if the value after decimal is greater than 0.5 it gets rounded up.

My desired output is

```
Time
07:34:24
08:44:43
08:11:38
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast it as `TIME(0)`:

```
Declare @Time Table 
(   
    Time Time
) 

Insert  @Time 
        (Time)
Select  '07:34:23.554'  Union All 
Select  '08:44:42.778'  Union All 
Select  '08:11:38.332'

Select  Cast(Time as Time(0)) As RoundedTime, 
        Time 
From    @Time
```

Output:

```
RoundedTime Time
----------------------------
07:34:24    07:34:23.5540000
08:44:43    08:44:42.7780000
08:11:38    08:11:38.3320000
```

A more permanent solution would be to change the datatype of the column in the table itself to `TIME(0)`:

```
Declare @Time Table 
(   
    Time Time(0)
) 

Insert  @Time 
        (Time)
Select  '07:34:23.554'  Union All 
Select  '08:44:42.778'  Union All 
Select  '08:11:38.332'

Select  *
From    @Time
```

Output:

```
Time
--------
07:34:24
08:44:43
08:11:38
```